# No operations defined in spec! (API Platform Core 3.0, Symfony 6.2, PHP 8.1)

Tags: api-platform.com

I installed the API Platform Core at v3.0.7 in an existing Symfony project (Symfony 6.2, PHP 8.1), and created a first API resource but for some reason I cannot get the API Platform to detect the resource's operations.

I tried both with Doctrine-managed entities and with plain old PHP objects + data providers. In both cases, Swagger's UI displayed my classes in the "Schemas" section but outputted a saddening "**No operations defined in spec!**" message above it.

Here is an overview of my setup:

```yaml
# config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Api/Model']
```

```php
<?php
# src/Api/Model/Team.php

namespace App\Api\Model;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Api\State\TeamProvider;

#[ApiResource(provider: TeamProvider::class)]
class Team
{
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    public int $id;

    public string $name;

    public string $slug;
}
```

```php
<?php
# src/Api/State/TeamProvider.php

namespace App\Api\State;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\CollectionOperationInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\State\ProviderInterface;
use App\Api\Model\Team;

/**
 * @implements ProviderInterface<Team>
 */
class TeamProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @param array<string,mixed> $uriVariables
     * @param array<mixed> $context
     */
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        $team = new Team();
        $team->id = 1;
        $team->id = "Test team";
        $team->slug = "test-team";

        if ($operation instanceof CollectionOperationInterface) {
            return [$team];
        }

        return $team;
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of Swagger's UI:

[image: Swagger's UI displaying the Team schemas with the message No operations defined in spec]

I also tried specifying certain operations via the attributes (`Get`, `GetCollection`, etc.) like so, but to no avail:

```php
// ...

#[ApiResource]
#[Get(provider: TeamProvider::class)]
class Team
{
    // ...
```

Am I missing something obvious, or is this supposed to work?

Could there be a bad interaction with another dependency?

### Edit

Okay, so I just tested an API call with a REST client and... it went through and returned the data as expected.

The issue seems to be only in Swagger's UI, where the operations are not detected and not displayed.

Is there something special I have to do for the operations to be documented and visible in Swagger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I realized that my project had custom serializers which didn't play nice with API Platform.

The API Platform relies on Symfony's built-in serializer. Re-defining and/or decorating that serializer can lead to issues, such as the one described above.

So the solution is to avoid redefining/decorating Symfony's serializer and to instead rely on custom normalizers and encoders whenever possible.